# Dynamic linker gives "cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" after using -L option

Tags: c, linker-errors

I have a project struct of a lib like this:

```
lib_ode/
    src/
        main/
            c/
                ode.c
            incluce/
                ode.h
        test/
            c/
                test_ode.c
            include/
    target/
        .objs/
        test/
```

In this struct I had compile my project with those 4 commands:

**(creating lib object)**

```
gcc  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -Wall -Isrc/main/include -c  -o "target/.objs/ode.o" src/main/c/ode.c
```

**(creating lib)**

```
gcc  -shared  target/.objs/ode.o -lm -o "target/libode.so"
```

**(creating test object)**

```
gcc  -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG -g -Wall -Isrc/main/include -c -Isrc/test/include -o target/.objs/test.o src/test/c/test_ode.c
```

**(creating test)**

```
gcc -L./target -lode target/.objs/test.o -o target/test/test.out
```

Then I tryed to run *target/test/test.out* and got this error.

**target/test/test.out: error while loading shared libraries: libode.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

In my understand, -L option includes a folder for link, and after the second command I can find a file at *target/libode.so*.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not the compiler giving the error message; your question title is wrong/misleading. The error is coming from the dynamic linker when you try to run the created executable.

Comment: Tks. I gonna fix the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created an executable dynamically linked against a library in an arbitrary directory. At runtime, the dynamic linker cannot find the library (it doesn't exist in any of the standard search paths) and so gives you the error.

To run the program, you could set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="`pwd`/target" target/test/test.out
```

You could also trying linking with `-rpath` (I've not tried this):

```
gcc -L./target -Wl,-rpath,./target -lode target/.objs/test.o -o target/test/test.out
```

(The above should "hardcode" the additional dynamic library search path in the executable. If you later move the library you will get an error again. I'm not sure if the path stored in the executable will be relative or absolute; if it's relative, you'll need to keep the executable and library at the same path relative to each other).